# What culture is a ComponentResourceManager using when it is instantiated in the designer?

Tags: c#, internationalization, resx

I'm explicitly setting the `CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to French right before the Component Resource Manager is being called for my user-control, but the default values are being pulled for the controls, not the French values.

Comment: A quick lookup on the source code of the ComponentResourceManager reveals it has 'public virtual  void ApplyResources(object  value, string objectName, CultureInfo  culture)' as signatures and in its implementation, if culture is provided as parameter, it overrides the Thread.CurrentUICulture usage.

Now, who's calling this method with what parameters is something i cannot say, but might be worth following up on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was debugging I wasn't running under the folder where the satellite assemblies were located.